# Java Arrays - Where too put Strings? Why doesn't it work?

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

My program should look like this:

> How many random numbers between 0 - 999 do you want? **12** (user
>   input)
>
> Here are the random numbers: 145 538 56 241 954 194 681 42 876 323 2
>   87
>
> These 7 numbers are even: 538 56 954 194 42 876 2
>
> These 5 numbers are odd: 145 241 681 323 87

I cannot seem too place the `String`s (`"These 7 numbers are even"` and `"These 5 numbers are odd"` at the right spot in the code. And how do I print the exact number (`7` and `5`) of even and odd numbers that are displayed in the `String`? The code does not seem to work either way for me. Do you see the problem(s)? Well I hope you can help me figure this out, have been doing this for 12 hours straight now.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SlumpadeTal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int evenCounter = 0;
        int oddCounter = 0; 

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many random numbers between 0 - 999 do you want?");
        int antal = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Here are the random numbers:");

        int[] arrayen = new int[antal];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayen.length; i++) {
            arrayen[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1);

            System.out.print(arrayen[i] + " ");
            if ((arrayen[i] % 2) == 0) {
                evenCounter++;
            }
            else {
                oddCounter++;
            }
        }
        int[] evenArray = new int [evenCounter];
        int[] oddArray = new int[oddCounter];
        evenCounter = 0;
        oddCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayen.length; i++){
            if ((arrayen[i] % 2) == 0) {
                evenArray[evenCounter] = arrayen[i];
                evenCounter++;
            }
            else {
                oddArray[oddCounter] = arrayen[i];
                oddCounter++;
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE I cannot use any class such as `ArrayList`, `Vector` and so on.

Comment: Print out the even/odd lists after the `for` loop, close to the very end of the method.

Comment: You will want to learn and then use basic debugging techniques, best by using a debugger such as one of the debuggers bundled with most IDE's including Eclipse and NetBeans. If you don't like using them, then at least use the "poor-man's debugger": a bunch of println statements generously sprinkled throughout your code to see what it's doing, what the state of its variables are, as it runs. Then later once your code is working well, you remove the `System.out.println(...)` debugging statements.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your output:

```
System.out.print("These "+evenCounter+" numbers are even: ");
for (int i = 0; i < evenCounter; i++){
    System.out.print(evenArray[i]+" ");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("These "+oddCounter+" numbers are odd: ");
for (int i = 0; i < oddCounter; i++){
    System.out.print(oddArray[i]+" ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Could work, there are other solutions. For example:

```
String evStr=new String();
String odStr=new String();

int curNum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++) {
    curNum = (int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1);

    System.out.print(curNum + " ");
    if ((curNum % 2) == 0) {
        evStr+=" "+curNum;
        evenCounter++;
    }
    else {
        odStr+=" "+curNum;
        oddCounter++;
    }
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("These "+evenCounter+" numbers are even: "+evStr);
System.out.println("These "+oddCounter+" numbers are odd: "+odStr);
```

So the whole second part with even/odd arrays of your code disappears. And there are no arrays at all any more.

Comment: It worked! You're the best of the best. Have a great one!

Answer (score 0):

When evenArray & oddArray have values after the last for-loop finished. You just use 2 another loop to print this 2 array.

**7** is **evenCounter + 1**

**5** is **oddCounter + 1**

Ex:
String s = "These " + (evenCounter + 1) + "numbers are even: " .... print your array.